# Angular 8 dynamic form - load 'select' options from callback

Tags: angular, typescript, forms

I have a service called `userService`, which has a method called `getUserFields()`. It returns an array of `Field` objects that will be rendered in my `newUserComponent`. For `select` elements, I set the options using an `options` key. However, in this scenario, for a select element which holds a list of roles, I need to load the options(the roles) from my database by calling the method `getUserRoles()` of the `rolesService`.

How can I implement callbacks that consume services in my dynamic forms workflow?

**userService.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Field } from '../../shared/models/field';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

    constructor() {}

    async getUserFields() {
        return [{
                type: 'text',
                label: 'Username',
                name: 'username',
                required: true,
            },
            {
                type: 'text',
                label: 'Surname',
                name: 'surname',
                required: true,
            },
            {
                type: 'select',
                label: 'Role',
                name: 'role',
                required: true,
                options: () => {
                    // call rolesService.getUserRoles()
                },
            },
            // etc...
        ];
    }
}
```

**newUserComponent.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from 'projects/recobros/src/app/core/services/user.service';
import { Field } from 'projects/recobros/src/app/shared/models/field';

// The `app-dynamic-field` component renders the field.
@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-user',
  template: `
    <form ngNativeValidate (ngSubmit)="createNewUser($event.target)">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let field of userFields | async">
            <app-dynamic-field [field]="field"></app-dynamic-field>
        </ng-container>
        <br>
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary">Crear usuario</button>
    </form>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./new-user.component.scss'],
})
export class NewUserComponent implements OnInit {
  userFields: Promise<Field[]>;
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userFields = this.userService.getUserFields();
  }

  createNewUser(form) {
    // create user...
  }
}
```